# Trouble with Angular .then() response data

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I have an angular app that's using a promise to fetch an array in a factory but I don't understand how to work with the `.then` argument. What exactly is response and how can I access the data within it? How would I say something like `response.objectProperty`? Why won't `console.log()` work in here?

```
myArray.getArrayObjects(objectProperty).then(function (response) { 
   $scope.model = response;
   console.log('Cannot test');
}
```

Comment: If your console.log is not firing, that means the ajax call failed. You can attach an error handler by putting a comma after that function and adding the error handler there: `.then(success, fail)`;

Comment: How would I reference response? I.e. response.property1;

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

The `.data` property corresponds to what would be passed in as the first argument to a `success()` handler, so what you want is:

```
myArray.getArrayObjects(objectProperty).then(function (response) { 
   $scope.model = response.data.objectProperty;
   console.log('Cannot test');
});
```